# Referenced Before Assignment Error In Python In A For Loop

Tags: python, variables

The Code I Am Receiving The Error From:

```
    for img in imgs:
        if kws.lower() in img['href'].lower():
            productLink = f'https://www.{site}.com' + img['href'] 
            price = requests.get(productLink)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(price.text, 'html.parser')
            itemPrice = soup.find(class_='money').text.split('$')[1] + '00'
        else:
            pass

    imageSrc = requests.get(productLink)
```

Error Message:

```
    imageSrc = requests.get(productLink)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'productLink' referenced before assignment
```

To Me This Doesn't Make Much Such Because I Clearly Assign The Variable Information.

Answer (score 0):

You Assigned the information in an if statement, if `if kws.lower() in img['href'].lower():` is false, then `prouductLink` has no value.

To fix

```py
for img in imgs:
        if kws.lower() in img['href'].lower():
            productLink = f'https://www.{site}.com' + img['href'] 
            price = requests.get(productLink)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(price.text, 'html.parser')
            itemPrice = soup.find(class_='money').text.split('$')[1] + '00'
            imageSrc = requests.get(productLink)
        else:
            pass
```

Or assign `imageSrc = ''` befor the if statement